# Floating Menu on Tooltips (z-index problem)

Tags: css, menu, tooltip, z-index, floating

I'm trying to have a floating menu on top of some text with tooltips but running into a z-index problem. I tried all different combinations of z-index values and placements with no success. I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious. Can someone help?

CODE:
https://tuw.fqd.mybluehost.me/sites/test.html

FLOATING HAMBURGER MENU SOURCE:
https://codepen.io/Cubbe/pen/RKEBby

TOOLTIP SOURCE:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

```
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1;` on `#menu` style and move `<div class="bg-cover reveal"></div>` at last position of divs. [Here](https://prnt.sc/4ZfSMrgF-3i6)

Comment: Your solution works! But after I copied your solution to my actual project, the floating menu is now showing below the overall background. And the menu items are now unclickable. There might be some conflicts in my main project. Could you take a look?

Comment: Your solution working in my test project...
https://tuw.fqd.mybluehost.me/sites/test2.html

Comment: Your solution incorporated into my actual project...
https://tuw.fqd.mybluehost.me/sites/menu_guide/cgi-bin/mmatch.cgi?a=results

Comment: Here's the link to the CSS... https://tuw.fqd.mybluehost.me/sites/menu_guide/css/mycss.css

Comment: @Collin As i can see you have used wrong format of comment. Please remove this comment or write in correct format. https://prnt.sc/6BphvYLun9CA

Comment: That was it...thanks for noticing the error. You're a great help!

Comment: Welcome! so could you please mark it answer as appreciation?

Answer (score 0):

you can put "z-index : -1;" in the ".tooltip" in your css code.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Adding z-index: -1; to .tooltip does solve the problem with the tooltip icons showing through the floating menu's background. However, now the tooltips itself no longer work (mouse over icon and tooltip does not show up). Any ideas?

Comment: https://tuw.fqd.mybluehost.me/sites/test3.html